# Why do people discourage using Tor with a VPN?

Tags: security, vpn

Why do Tor experts discourage using Tor and a VPN at the same time? Is it because of the network fingerprint, latency, or that there is no point to it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's totally not a problem - using Tor with VPN, but:

- Use direct connection *with static IP address and ORPort opened*, it will help. Also keep your node running 24/7
- If you can not connect to directories(banned by IP addresses and/or protocol DPI filter) - use OBFSv4 bridges *or* set your router box up with VPN the way that directories will be reached via VPN but other addresses are not
- Run DirPort directory mirror, so it will help the consensus

That's actually *when and how* you can have a benefit using VPN with Tor. Other scenarios will not break things up, but will not make any profit too. A quick note - about the non-reachable ORport through VPN: quite a lot of nodes do not have ORPort reachable, like ones behind the NAT, so it does not make a sensible difference.